# Xamarin android Glide webp animation

Tags: android, xamarin, animation, android-glide, webp

I'm using this [library](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/master/Android/Glide) (Xamarin binding library of Glide), to display Gif in my app. But I would like to display Webp animations to save some space in my app.

```
Glide.With(context)
     .Load(url)
     .Into(imageView);
```

But the animation is locked on the first frame and didn't play [(webp animation example)](http://echiquierbriochin.fr/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/ZeMarmot.webp).

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known [issue](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/issues/8593).

Right now, Glide has no built-in webp support and defaults to the system.It seems like Glide will work when you introduce some libraries that support WebP.

Comment: oh okay. Too bad it's not supported yet. Do you think it will be one day?

Comment: @SamihELSAKHAWI It is hard to say, after all, that such a request was made two years ago.And you could consider using other libraries.

Comment: I just updated my app to use AnimatedImageDrawable API on devices >= android sdk 28, and for the other devices, i still use Gif.